# useLazyQuery not firing in Promise all

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to refetch the data in from a apollo server but cant get it to work. 
I do two mutaions and push them into an array. 
I then want to, when they finsih, get the data and re-populate a graph.

```
    Promise.all(promises)
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result)
      console.log(id)
      return getGraph({
        variables: {
          id: id
        },
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
      });
    })
    .catch();
```

I can see that it logs the result and correct ID. Also changed to network only so it wont look in cache. 
Any suggestions on what might be wrong?

Br

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, which I think is partly because you don't actually show us the code that calls `useLazyQuery`

Comment: getGraph is fetcherfunction, sorry. But its solved no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `getGraph` is fetcher - callback returned by `useLazyQuery`.

Unfortunately it does not return `Promise` but returns `void`(according to [Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#result-1)). There is [existing issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/5268) in Github on that but I'm not sure if that ever will be implemented.

See, for hooks it's much more natural to return some data on each render. At one render you have some flag `isLoading = true` and next render you are getting `isLoading = false` and some non-empty `data`. If you introduce `Promise` that can be resolved or rejected regardless of component's rendering cycle things become really messy.

If you don't like that approach(or really need to sync some query with anoter one) as a workaround you can run [`query`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#ApolloClient.query) on `client` accessed through [`ApolloConsumer`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-common/#apolloconsumer).

[UPD] as @Jedi Schmedi wrote in comments, fetcher actually returns `Promise` but in more recent version(`^3.1.2`) of `apollo`. So it could be a workaround although I'm not sure if that API is not stable and can be changed OR docs are misleading.

Comment: Sorry, left out that getGraph is the fetcher. I updated versions and now it works. So maybe there was a buggy behaviour that they fixed.

Comment: wow, what a surprise! their docs explicitly says it returns nothing!

Comment: "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.2", Had 3.0.0

Comment: I tried "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3" but got no promise in useLazyQuery